# Maneiras para refatorar longos forms?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, refatoração

Estou tendo uma frustação muito grande na criação de novos formulários dentro do projeto da minha equipe. Nós lidamos com informações de pacientes, ou seja, muita informação. Quando vamos criar os componentes de forms para cada view de insert/edit, acabamos definindo um `formValues` dentro do `data` para armazenar todos os campos que serão utilizados como `v-model`. O problema é que, ao realizar isso, acabamos tendo um código muito extenso, como o exemplo abaixo:

```js
export default {
  // ...
  data: () => ({
    formValues: {
      nome: null,
      nomeMae: null,
      telefone: null,
      celular: null,
      convenios: [],
      // Mais propriedades...
    }
  }),
  
  methods: {
    savePaciente() {
      const payload = cloneDeep(this.formValues);
      // Código de processo
    }
  },
}
```

Esse exemplo parece pequeno, porém, quando o componente cresce, quando regras de negócio entram, quando outras tratativas aparecem, esse arquivo se torna cada vez mais extenso, pelo fato de lidar com tantos campos. Fico me perguntando se existe alguma forma de refatorar esses forms, deixa-los menores e menos verbosos.

Comment: Como é que o código HTML fica? também fica verboso aí? Eu costumo ter um ficheiro à parte que tem um manifesto dos campos, um objeto que descreve os campos com label, valor inicial, etc... Forms são "verbosas"...

Comment: @Sergio Sim, normalmente o template acaba se tornando muito extenso, por conta de ter diversos componentes de inputs para cada um daqueles campos do formValues

Comment: Podes adicionar um exemplo de uma form completo? curioso como tens o código no template

Answer (score -2):

Você pode separar os componentes para que você possa trabalhar de uma maneira mais isolada com a lógica de cada um.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um pequeno exemplo de como você poderia separar os seus components.

O exemplo funcionando está aqui https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsptstackoverflowcomquestions450846-dm6g1?file=/src/App.vue

```
<!-- App.vue -->

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input-nome v-model="formValues.nome"/>
    <input-mae v-model="formValues.nomeMae"/>
    <input-telefone v-model="formValues.telefone"/>
    <select-cidade v-model="formValues.cidade"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import InputNome from "./components/custom/InputNome";
import InputMae from "./components/custom/InputMae";
import InputTelefone from "./components/custom/InputTelefone";
import SelectCidade from "./components/custom/SelectCidade";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    InputNome,
    InputMae,
    InputTelefone,
    SelectCidade
  },
</script>

<!-- InputMae.vue -->

<template>
  <input v-model="data" placeholder="Nome da mãe">
</template>

<script>

import BaseInputValue from "../generics/BaseInputValue.vue";

export default {
  name: "InputMae",
   extends: BaseInputValue
};
</script>

<!-- InputNome.vue -->

<template>
  <input v-model="data" placeholder="Nome completo">
</template>


<script>
import BaseInputValue from "../generics/BaseInputValue.vue";

export default {
  name: "InputNome",
   extends: BaseInputValue
};
</script>

<!-- BaseInputValue -->

<script>
export default {
  name: "BaseInputValue",
  props: ['value'],
  computed : {
    data: {
      get: function(){
        return this.value;
      },
      set: function(newValue){
        this.$emit('input', newValue)
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```